# Xamarin.Forms: Animated page/layout transition

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So let's say I have in a Xamarin.Forms app, a `MainPage` with following layout:

```
+------------------------------+
|                              |
|     +-------+  +-------+     |
|     |       |  |       |     |
|     |Button1|  |Button2|     |
|     |       |  |       |     |
|     +-------+  +-------+     |
|                              |
+------------------------------+
```

and now after the user taps on `Button1` I want the page to transition to following layout:

```
+------------------------------+
|---+                          |
||B1|   +-------+  +-------+   |
+---+   |       |  |       |   |
|       |Button3|  |Button4|   |
+---+   |       |  |       |   |
||B2|   +-------+  +-------+   |
|---+                          |
+------------------------------+
```

The tricky part is, that I want a nice animated transition where:

- Buttons 3 and 4 are sliding from the far right
- Buttons 1 and 2 are moving and scaling with ease to their target position on the left.

Is there any way to implement such behavior in xamarin.forms xaml?

The only approach that I can think of right now, is to use an `AbsoluteLayout` and set absolute values in pixels for the button initial positions (or their containers). And to do the transition by calling for each element `TranslateTo` and `ScaleTo` methods with proper parameters to set the target layout.

But if I want to have more layouts and transition between them, and support more screen resolutions I guess that approach can quickly become hardly maintainable.

If I would have those layouts on separate pages, and make such custom transition between pages, I guess then it becomes even harder, if possible at all.

Any tips how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared element transitions to move things when navigate from page 1 to page 2 in a NavigationPage container.

I made a nuget package to use shared animation transition in xamarin forms xaml, here the source code:

https://github.com/Evolutionlab/Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions

Here the Nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions/